# nested routes are not working with react-admin

Tags: react-admin

Im trying this

```
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}  >
            <Resource name="menuitems" options={{ label: 'Item' }} list={MenuitemList} create{MenuitemCreate} edit={MenuitemEdit} >
                <Route path=":id/menuitem-subcategories"  component={<MenuitemSubcategoryList/>}/>
            </Resource>
</Admin>
```

But it gives me the error
[undefined] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

I want to have nested routes with react-admin

Comment: I don't see any obvious issue with the code. Can you confirm you are using react-admin 4.7 minimum, and that you are importing `Route` from `react-router-dom`?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation explains, react-admin supports [custom routing](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Routing.html) and [nested routes](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html#nested-resources).

It seems to me that there is an error in the properties passed to the `<Route>` component. The `component` property does not exist but the `element` property does:

```
<Route
    path=":id/menuitem-subcategories"
-   component={<MenuitemSubcategoryList />}
+   element={<MenuitemSubcategoryList />}
/>
```

To make this work, make sure to import `Route` from `react-router-dom`.